# Error saving workshared model using Design Automation API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am currently facing issues while saving the work shared model(C4R model) when the changes are made using the Design Automation API. [Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdqgC.png)

However, the same issue does not arise when the model is not work-shared.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated on Jan 10th, 2024:

Revit Cloud Worksharing model is now supported by Revit Design Automation service directly, for details, please check the blog
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-api-supports-revit-cloud-model

---

Unfortunately, accessing Revit Cloud Worksharing models is restricted at the moment, please check https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/restrictions/ for all the restrictions for Design Automation Revit.

Comment: @AmitKumarAman You are welcome, could you please accept the answer as solution so it also benefits people who having same problem to get the answer quick in future, thanks:)